# Are there faeries in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

I'm currently doing a bit of a "Fairy of the Fountain" encounter in my game, and the only thing I need now is a reliable stat block for the fairy. You know... just in case.

I opened up the Monster Manual and found that there exists a Faerie Dragon, but not a Faerie proper. What gives? Am I missing something? Are they located somewhere else? Is there a reasonable alternative anywhere in these books?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### There isn't a generic faerie, but there are various Fey creatures.

Pixie (MM p.253) and Sprite (MM p.283) probably come closest to what you're imagining. Little elfin creatures with wings, and all.

Satyrs and Dryads are also in the MM, and are classic Fey archetypes. Blink Dog, Green Hag, and Sea Hag are the only other Fey-typed entries in the MM, but they're likely *not* the sort of thing you think of when you say "faerie."

And, of course, there's the elves....

Comment: It's worth noting that all the creatures mentioned here are listed as natives of the Feywild in the DMG section on the planes. It also says in the same section that the Feywild is also known as the Plane of Faerie, which supports the idea that "faerie" is a fairly broad term that covers multiple creatures.

Comment: I actually really like the idea that at the end of the quest, the fairy of the fountain turns out to be a Green Hag.

Answer (score 11):

The Pixie (MM p253) might be what you are looking for.
It's a tiny fey. With superior Invisibility and some magical tricks.

Sprites (MM p283) could also work if you want a fey with weapons.

Dryads (MM p121) are not exactly faeries but they are wood spirits and are medium sized.